# C/C++) Why Have Read and Write Access Been Omitted after Run the Program?

Tags: pointers, printf, scanf, fclose

when I try to write and read into/onto the txt file in C, it hadn't worked well after run the file.

There was no error when run that file, but I don't know why it's no working.

and in output.txt, meaningless result had been written.

(nothing was in input.txt)

(-858993460 was in output.txt)

I attach my code and result pictrue.

*After I got comment from Adrian, I added return value to see what value is returned. Reason of the error was I didn't put anyting in input.txt. I figure out that I'm supposed to put something into input.txt before starting the code! 
 After I put number 6 into input.txt, It worked well!! I'm sincerely appreciated to Adrian. Have a good day. Lifesavier!

After I put 6 into input.txt, Result : [image]
Captures that I created output.txt and input.txt :
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 FILE* in, *out;
 int n,m,o,p,q;
 p = fopen_s(&in, "input.txt", "r");
 q = fopen_s(&out, "output.txt", "w");

 m = fscanf_s(in, "%d", &n);
 o = fprintf(out, "%d\n", n);
 printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", p, q, m, o, n);

 fclose(in);
 fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: You should check the return values of `fopen_s` and `fscanf_s` (and print them out to the console) to see if those calls succeeded.

Comment: I'm sorry I got lost how to edit that code, could you edit that one if you don't mind? Thanks Adrian.

Comment: Add another two `int` variables (say, `p` and `q`) and do `p = fopen_s(&in...)` and `q = fopen_s(&out...` and then `printf` `p` and `q` like you have with `m` and `o`. Then let us know what the values for those four variables are.

Comment: I did and I got 0, 0, -1, 11 like picture attached. But still I can not understand those from.

Comment: OK, the two zeros indicated that the `fopen_s` calls worked. The `11` indicated how many characters the `fprintf_s` call wrote, and the `-1` (which is `EOF`) indicates that `fscanf_s` failed! Maybe show us the contents of your input file. (Although I just re-read your question and you say "nothing was in input.txt" - so you can't read an integer from it!!)

Comment: oh my.. So you mean I have to put something into "input.txt" ! I will do it right now. hang on plz

Comment: It's working.... Thank you so much... really really..!!!!!